# When trying to dump a database I get error 2 or "access denied"

Tags: mysql

Need to dump a database.

I am using

```
mysqldump -uroot -p volunteer -r "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/UGHWORKsql;
```

I keep receiving

> "access denied" or  Usage  mysqldump [options] database [tables] or mysqldump [options]-- databases[options] DB1 (DB2, DB3)… or mysqldump [options] --all-databases [options].

What do I do?
Thank you

Comment: Please add some details and explanation

Answer (score 0):

If volumteer is your database

USe

```
mysqldump -uroot -p volunteer > "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/UGHWORKsql;
```

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-setting.html)